Internal audio not working on ThinkPad T14 G1 (Intel, Ubuntu 24.04)
I installed a fresh version of (K)Ubuntu 24.04 on my ThinkPad T14 G1 (Intel) about two weeks ago without any issues. However, I've suddenly lost audio input and output for the internal speakers and headphone jack. USB and Bluetooth headsets still work fine.
Anyone with an answer for this issue?
General information:
$inxi -MAa
[...]
Audio:
Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS vendor: Lenovo
driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl
alternate: snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl bus-ID: 00:1f.3
chip-ID: 8086:02c8 class-ID: 0403
API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-45-generic status: kernel-api
tools: alsactl,alsamixer,amixer
Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active with:1: pipewire-pulse
status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
tools: pactl,pw-cat,pw-cli,wpctl

Here are the steps I’ve already tried, without any success (after numerous reboots):
deleted ~/.local/state/wireplumber &
- $ systemctl --user restart wireplumber*.service
- $ sudo alsa force-reload​​
- $ ​sudo apt reinstall pipewire pipewire-bin pipewire-pulse
- $ ​systemctl --user --now enable pipewire pipewire-pulse​
- $ sudo apt purge pulseaudiode
- Checked alsamixer for any MM channel (nope)
- $ sudo apt install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio

The status of pipewire itself looks quite normal to me:
$ systemctl --user status pipewire-pulse 
● pipewire-pulse.service - PipeWire PulseAudio
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-pulse.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-10-06 15:40:17 CEST; 35min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire-pulse.socket
   Main PID: 1516 (pipewire-pulse)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18651)
     Memory: 7.7M (peak: 8.3M)
        CPU: 87ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire-pulse.service
             └─1516 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse

However, it doesn't find anything for output/input without an USB/bluetooth headset connected:
$ wpctl status
[...]
Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  *   33. Dummy Output                        [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:277: no soundcards found...

